# How can I calculate the coordinates of the given points?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, trigonometry, angle

How can I find the coordinates of the points $x_{1a}$ and $x_{2a}$ from the given diagram. The points marked in purple are the ones for which we have coordinates and every distance marked with letter $d$,$dd$,$dt$ are distances which we know with an angle $\varphi_{\mbox{drift}}$.
The $x_{1a}$ and $x_{2a}$ are in the second picture. In the first picture they are only considering the centre point of the object and in the second picture they are considering the vertices of the object. I am still confused on how to get the coordinates of the $x_{1a}$ and $x_{2a}$. I have attached the images here. Your help would be appreciated as I did geometry 24 years back and it is hard to recollect everything. Thank you
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is no x1a, x2 or theta on either picture that I can see. There is no obvious relationship between the two pictures. You are going to have to work a bit harder to explain what is going on before anyone will commit their time I should think

Comment: @Paul I have done some changes now.

Comment: Is the line corresponding to $afst$ perpendicular to the line given by $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$? In other words, is that the distance of the Object from the line?

Comment: @AlvinL It is perpendicular as it is the shortest distance from the object to the line given by (x1,y1), (x2,y2).

Comment: Where are $x_{1a}$ and $x_{2a}$ on the first diagram?

Comment: @AlvinL In the first diagram they have not given the x1a and x2a as they are only considering the centre point of the object and the link points to calcualte minimal distance. In the second diagram they are taking the dimension of the object as well as drift angle therefore hopefuly x1a and x2a will be the points related to the dimension of the object.

Comment: It is a bit confusing. Please indicate the originating 4-bar mechanism for fuller context, what is given and what is required, in a table. Also there is a minor contradiction. Last two lines given should be, if as per sketch: $ d_{link}=d_1+d_2
, d_1=d+dd~$

Comment: The given things are the cooridinates of the starting of the link and the ending of the link which are x1,x2,y1,y2 and the object coordinates, object dimension and the phi_drift. We have to find the coordinate of x1a and x2a. @Narasimham